# Redirección o cargar después del login woocommerce (error)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

mi wordpress con woocommerce tengo que realizar dos veces la acción de introducir login para poder ver en el menú “mi cuenta” en el menú principal, es como si la primera vez no cargara correctamente.

Si me identifico una sola vez en el menú sigue igual pero si paso a otra pagina ya visualizo el menú correcto de “mi cuenta”.

He realizado varias pruebas para descartar errores:

-He desactivado los pluguins y el error seguía igual.
-He subido una versión anterior de la misma plantilla y tiene el mismo error.

También he pensado que podría ser tema de cargar solo el header ya que las cookies de session están iniciadas en la primera vez.

Estoy buscando algún código para el functions.php que me resuelva este problema.

He probado:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'login_redirect',10, 3);

function login_redirect() {

//codigo comentado para realizar pruebas.
//return home_url();
//wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
// //return $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
//$redirect_url = home_url();
   // return wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url );

}
```

---

```
function test_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    $redirect_to =  home_url();
 
    return $redirect_to;
}
 
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'test_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

---

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function( $url, $query, $user ) {
    return home_url();
}, 10, 3 );
```

por ahora no encuentro solución.

Perdón por el cacao y gracias ;-)

Comment: Parece ser mas bien un problema de cache, tienes cache activo en tu sitio?

Comment: un pluguin de cloudflare y cache (https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cloudflare-page-cache/), pero desactive el pluguin y seguia con el problema.  :-( no se si podria ser por la parte de cloudflare.